# The usage of new in C++

Tags: c++, binary-tree

super dumb question, I want to create a binary tree in c++, and the following is my code

```
include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct tree{
    tree * child_left = NULL;
    tree * child_right = NULL;
    int root;
    tree * parent = NULL;
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    tree *t1 = new tree;
    tree *t2 = new tree;
    tree *t3 = new tree;
    tree *t4 = new tree;
    tree *t5 = new tree;
    tree *t6 = new tree;
    tree *t7 = new tree;
    t4->root = 1;
    t5->root = 3;
    t6->root = 6;
    t7->root = 9;
    t2->root = 2;
    t2->child_left = t4;
    t2->child_right = t5;
    t3->root = 7;
    t3->child_left = t6;
    t3->child_right = t7;
    t1->root = 4;
    t1->child_left = t2;
    t1->child_right = t3;
    cout << t1->child_left->child_right->root;
    return 0;
}
```

This can actually work but if I remove the new when declaring those node, xcode will have error like (Thread1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code = 1, address = 0x10)).

I wonder what cause the Thread problem and why I need to use new when declaring these nodes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you don't use `new tree`, then your pointers are not initialized and you get undefined behavior when you try to indirect through them.

Comment: Does `= NULL` do anything in the context of a `struct`? I thought you had to write a constructor to set that sort of thing.

Comment: @tadman new in c++11

Comment: @tadman: C++11 adds the ability to initialize non-static `class`/`struct` members in their declarations.

Comment: Working [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3c15efb17171ac27) without `new` :-)

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks. Wasn't sure if/when that came into play.

Comment: You can't use the value of a variable until you assign it a variable. If you just do `tree* t1;`, then `t1` has no particular value, so trying to use its value, for example with `t1->root = 4;` makes no sense -- what `tree` are you trying to set the `root` member of? You haven't created a `tree`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are declaring pointers to a tree object.  Without using new, you aren't allocating any objects for those pointers to point at.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
tree t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7;

  t4.root = 1;
  t5.root = 3;
  t6.root = 6;
  t7.root = 9;
  t2.root = 2;
  t2.child_left = &t4;
  t2.child_right = &t5;
  t3.root = 7;
  t3.child_left = &t6;
  t3.child_right = &t7;
  t1.root = 4;
  t1.child_left = &t2;
  t1.child_right = &t3;
  cout << t1.child_left->child_right->root;
  return 0;
}
```

This takes care of creating the objects on the stack which are then automatically destructed when the scope ends.

`tree` should probably have a ctor that takes arguments so that you are creating an object instead of a bag of data.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `new` keyword actually creates the object the pointer is pointing to. Without the `new` keyword, the pointer is uninitialized, and dereferencing it results in undefined behavior.

Furthermore, properly-written code must always `delete` all objects that were instantiated with `new`, in order to avoid leaking memory. Not needed in this trivial example, but it's better to learn good habits early on.

Answer (score 0):

You require the new statement when initializing pointers because all your node/tree variables are pointers. It is quite common to use pointers when developing data structures due to the nature of all of them (dynamic number of elements, the operations that can be performed on the data structures rely almost always on heap allocated values, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I thought I should just point out that when you are using the keyword `new` you are in fact creating a variable on the heap and a pointer to this variable on the stack. If you did not use the word `new` you would only be creating a pointer on the stack and you are not creating a variable.

In c++ the whenever you allocate something on the heap you must also remember to delete it when you no longer require it anymore. Unlike variables on the stack these do not automatically get deleted as they never go out of scope. You need to use the keyword `delete` for this otherwise you will get 'memory leaks'.

I suggest you take a look at this quick tutorial to clarify your dynamic programming concepts: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/ .

Hope that gives you some insight into what's happening!